# new Image/new Table/new Button errors Typescript on compile

Tags: typescript, actions-on-google

I'm creating a Google action and I'm running into issues with the `new` keyword for certain elements. For instance here:

```
conv.ask(new Table({
  title: ``,
  subtitle: '',
  image: new Image({
    url: '',
    alt: 'Logo'
  }),
  columns: [
    {
      header: 'Line',
      align: 'CENTER',
    },
    {
      header: 'Destination',
      align: 'LEADING',
    },
    {
      header: 'Car',
      align: 'TRAILING',
    },
    {
      header: 'Arrival',
      align: 'TRAILING',
    },
  ],
  rows: timetableCells,
  buttons: new Button({
    title: 'Button Title',
    url: 'https://github.com/actions-on-google'
  }),
}))
```

Anywhere `new` is referenced I end up with an error on compile:

> src/index.ts(21,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Table'.
>
> src/index.ts(24,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Image'.
>
> src/index.ts(47,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Button'.

Here's my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I understand why this error throws, but I'm not sure which library these are being sourced from in Google's [examples](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yikes, well that was a lot more obvious then I thought it was going to be. Leaving this here incase it helps anyone else.

```
import {dialogflow, Image, Table, Button} from 'actions-on-google';
```